# Convert numpy symmetric array to and from Voigt notation

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array representing a stack of 3x3 symmetric matrices:

```
a[n] = [[a11, a12, a31],[a12, a22, a23],[a31, a23, a33]]
```

I would like to convert to and from Voigt notation:

```
a[n] = [a11, a22, a33, a12, a23, a31]
```

What's the most efficient way to implement that?

Comment: do your input array always 3X3?!

Comment: In fact it is the other way around, my input is always in Voigt notation, so it is always (...,6)

Comment: OK, How do you want to fill the other three values? you want to convert 6 values to 3X3=9 values

Comment: Each 3x3 array must be symmetric so that a = a.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

```
def symmetric(x):
   x = np.asarray(x)
   assert x.shape[-1] == 6, "Last dimension must be of shape 6"
   if x.ndim == 1:
   x = x[None]
   y = np.zeros(x.shape[:-1] + (3, 3))
   y[..., 0, :] = np.moveaxis(np.array([x[:, 0], x[:, 5], x[:, 4]]), 0, -1)
   y[..., 1, :] = np.moveaxis(np.array([x[:, 5], x[:, 1], x[:, 3]]), 0, -1)
   y[..., 2, :] = np.moveaxis(np.array([x[:, 4], x[:, 3], x[:, 2]]), 0, -1)
   return np.squeeze(y)

def voigt(x):
   x = np.asarray(x)
   assert x.ndim >= 2, "Array must at least 2D"
   assert x.shape[-2:] == (3, 3), "Last 2 dimensions must be of shape (3, 3)"
   if x.ndim == 2:
      x = x[None]
   y = np.array([x[..., 0, 0], x[..., 1, 1], x[..., 2, 2], x[..., 1, 2], x[..., 0, 2], x[..., 0, 1]]).T
   return np.squeeze(y)
```